# Use a Sketch Up 2016 Model with babylon JS

Tags: sketchup, babylonjs

I'm looking for a path to be able to use a Sketch UP 3D Model in babylon JS on a simple web page.

I think I have to convert the .skp file to a babylon JS Compatible format but I don't find a solution.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I want to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I know is to use the blender->babylon exporter.

You can install blender from [Here](https://www.blender.org/)

Then you can install the exporter by following these [instructions](https://doc.babylonjs.com/exporters/installing__the_babylon_exporter)

And finally, from sketchup, you can export your component in collada format (.dae), import it in blender then export it to babylon format.

After that, you can drag& drop the generated .babylon file on [this page](http://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) to see if your model was correctly generated. For most objects, I had no problem...